# DELETE different resources with one requests - Is it ok or we should try to mix those resources to one

Tags: rest, api, restful-url

Let assume that I have a collection with /playrequests endpoint. It is a collection (list) for those players who want to find another player to start a match.

The server will check this collection periodically and if it finds two unassigned players, it will create another resource in another collection with /quickmatchs endpoint and also change (for example) a field in the PlayRequests collection for both players to shows that they are assigned to a quickMatch.

At this point, players can send a PUT or PATCH request to set the (for example) "ready" field of their related quickMach resource to true. so the server and each of them can find out that if both of them is ready and the match can be started.

**(The Issue Part Is Below Part...)**

Also, before a the playRequests assigned to a match and also after they assigned to it, they can send a DELETE request to /playrequests endpoint to tell the server that they want to give up the request. So if the match doesn't create yet, It is ok. the resource related to the player will remove from playRequests collection. but if player assigned to a match, the server must delete the related playRequest and also it must delete the related quickMatch resource from the quickMatchs collection. ( and also we should modify the playRequest related to another player to indicate that it's unassigned now. or we can check and change it later when he to check the status of his related resources in both collection. It is not the main issue for now. )

**So, my question is that** is it ok to change a resource that is related to the given end point and also change another resource accordingly, If it is necessary? ( I mean is it ok to manipulate different resources with different endpoints in one request? I don't want to send multiple requests.) or I need to mix those two collections to avoid such an action?

I know that many things ( different strategies ) are possible but I want to know that (from the viewpoint of RESTFUL) what is standard/appropriate and what is not? (consider that I am kinda new to restful)

Answer (score 0):

> it ok to change a resource that is related to the given end point and also change another resource accordingly

Yes, and there are consequences.

Suppose we have two resources, `/fizz` and `/buzz`, and the representations of those resources are related via some implementation details on the server.  On the client, we have accessed both of these resources, so we have cached copies of each of them.

The potential issue here is that the server changes the representations of these resources together, but as far as the client is concerned, they are separate.

For instance, if the client sends an unsafe request to change `/fizz`, a successful response message from the server will invalidate the locally cached copy of that representation, but the stale representation of `/buzz` does not get evicted.  In effect, the client now has a view of the world with version 0 `/buzz` and version 1 `/fizz`.

Is that OK?  "It depends" -- will expensive things happen to you if your clients are in a state of unmatched representations?  Can you patch over the "problem" in other ways (for instance, by telling the client to check resources for updates more often)?

Comment: I think I got my answer. so It is OK and the consequences are my responsibility. It is an API for a game and it will not be published publicly. Also, Yes the client will check for Updates periodically. Also, not all of the methods are open for both endpoints. I think all these things will reduce the consequences to near the zero. am I right? So As I understood, It Is standard and has no conflict with restful philosophy, Right?